# Want SNS alert repeatedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I had setup an Alert for CPU utilization on EC2 instance. Created one SNS topic to send alerts on mail. It sends me an alert when CPU utilization goes to ALARM state but I want repeated alerts till ALARM state get resolved. Please help me... I'm newbie to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get repeated notifications after getting into the ALARM state. As the alarm is entering the ALARM state only once that means the notification via Amazon SNS will be sent only once.

Autoscaling policy will be triggered by the same alarm. But mail will be sent only once.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is setup a Lambda function with a [CloudWatch event trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) so that it runs periodically, and inside it call the [CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html). Then, simply check if it is above or below your preferred threshold (or if you want, whether or not it's in Alarm state) and [publish a message to SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html). There are a lot of SDK documentations on how to use these API's with your preferred language.

Comment: Thank you @Deiv for your response. But currently I'm not thinking about Lambda due to pricing concerns. I will think on it in future.

Comment: Understandable, however it's worth mentioning that Lambdas are fairly cheap if you keep it low memory and low timeout (which in your case is what you would need). There is also the free tier if you are still in that. Good luck!